# Make relationship based on other relationships in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

suppose i have following relationships stored in neo4j.

```
A->B,A->D,C->B,C->E
```

Here A, C are of same label nodes and B, E also are of same label nodes.
What is the cypher query to count how many nodes A and C have in common?
 Based on that I want to make to a relationship between A and C.  I would like to add a relationship rank between them and give it some value say 0.5 because 1 node common. What would that query look like?

Answer (score 0):

To return the number of common nodes between ***A*** and ***C*** match a pattern that has ***A*** at one and ***C*** a the other with an intermediary node.  Then count the occurrences of the intermediary node.

```
match (:TypeOne {name: 'A'})--(common)--(:TypeOne {name: 'C'})
return count(common)
```

If you want to create a relationship directly between ***A*** and ***C*** as a result of the match then use `merge` or `create` with the ***A*** and ***C*** nodes. And use `set` to add a value to the newly created relationship.

Something like this should satisfy your requirements.

```
match (a:TypeOne {name: 'A'})--(common)--(c:TypeOne {name: 'C'})
with a, c, count(common) as in_common
merge (a)-[rel:COMMON_WITH]->(c)
set rel.value = in_common * 0.5
return *
```

Comment: but suppose I have a csv file and there are different nodes of same type A,C then i have to make relationships between all these nodes according to  common nodes between them.Then what should be the query ?

Comment: I presume each line of the csv file contains the keys (or some identifier) for the two nodes that are being sought.  And you would replace the **'A'** and **'C'**matches in the query above  with the actual nodes you are looking for (e.g. line.a_node and line.c_node).